# Flutter: Await HTTP Request going in loop

Tags: flutter, dart

I am facing strange issue while doing http async request. I know the reason why it is failing but don't know how to fix it.
Here is my code.

```
    Future userLogin() async{
 try{
    String email = emailController.text;
    String password = passwordController.text;
    var url = 'http://192.168.100.4:8080/myapp/loginnexec.php';

      // Store all data with Param Name.
      var data = {'email': email, 'password' : password };
     print(data);
      // Starting Web API Call.
      var response = await http.post(url, body: json.encode(data));

      // Getting Server response into variable.

      final message = loginFromJson(response.body);
    if(response.statusCode == 200){
        setState(() {
          visible = false;
        });

      }

    }
     }catch(e){
     .....
     }
    }
```

If my web server is down or file is not available then it is going to an infinite loop. I mean all the time i am able to see the same JSON data which is this (var data = {'email': email, 'password' : password }.

I want to know how can I prevent it from going in a loop. It looks like it is trying to reach to webserver for data and if it is not getting the data then trying again.

I am not sure I have explained it properly or not.

Sorry about my bad English.

Comment: can you share, from where you call this method "userLogin"

Comment: @ShudiptoTrafder i am calling it from button click event.

Comment: so, what do you want ? after some try it should stop?

Comment: where is your `try` block?

Comment: @VirenVVarasadiya I want it to stop after some try or some timeout option. When i run it last time it was going more than 20 times then i stopped it manually.

Comment: @LoVe try block added in the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set a `timeout` on the `Future` so it resolves after a certain time:

```
await http.post('someurl').timeout(Duration(seconds: 5),onTimeout: (){
    throw Exception();
    //or you can also
    // return null;
  });
```

Comment: Thanks Love. Let me try this one. Voted up.

Comment: Instead of this throw Exception(); Can i show a alert or snackbar?

Comment: It worked. It is getting timedout in 5 sec and i can show a snackbar about that. Thanks a ton. Answer accepted.